# How do I shink/scale a point according to mean value of the dataset?

Tags: python, plotly, figure, plotly-python

I have code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

d1 = ...
d2 = ...

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=d1.x, y=d1.y, fill='tozeroy', name='Old',)) # fill down to xaxis
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=d2.x, y=d2.y, fill='tonexty', name='New',)) # fill to trace0 y
fig.show()
```

The result :

[image]

Because the `X=0` point is extremly larger than others(mean value) , I have to remove it to plot a nice plot :

[image]

But actully I also want plot `X=0` point  like :

[image]

Is any good way to do this ?

For example:

1. I can detect which points over mean + 3 variance
2. Make those points scale to max of left points
3. Add label to these points to indicate the true value

Comment: What do you want the scaled value to be? You want it to be the mean of the data or...?

Comment: @nicolaskruchten I want detect the outlier value by mean, then show it in some scale(max value of left? ) with labels indicate what they truely are .  Other intuitive ways are welcome.